# tfpt /uploadattachment - unable to determine source control server

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-power-tools

Trying to upload txt file as attachment to workitems in TFS but I get this:

"Unable to determine source control server."

I tried tf workspaces collection:"http..." and it gives me a list of workspaces but doesn't do anything.

Upload command was typed like this:

tfpt workitem /uploadattachment 1234 fileName.txt

Interesting, downloadattachment works, and changing title works, just uploadattachment doesn't.

any advices??

Comment: Did you try this: tfpt workitem /uploadattachment 1234 fileName.txt /collection:xxx?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the `/collection:uri` option.

Comment: I have specified it, I just didn't write it here.
tf workspaces /collection:"http://asdf:8080/tfs/asdf"